# Laravel 4: how to update multiple fields in an Eloquent model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

How can I update multiple fields in an Eloquent model? Let's say I got it like this:

```
$user = User::where("username", "=", "rok");
```

And then I have all these model parameters:

```
$new_user_data = array("email" => "rok@rok.com", "is_superuser" => 1, ...);
```

I can't just do:

```
$user->update($new_user_data);
```

What's the proper way? I hope not a `foreach`.

The following does work, however. Is this the way to go?

```
User::where("id", "=", $user->id)->update($new_user_data);
```

The problem with the last one (besides it being clunky) is that when using it from an object context, the updated fields are not visible in the `$this` variable.

Comment: Yes, I think that when updating several columns, the `update()` function only works when updating the Model directly. Otherwise, you have to use `fill()` and `save()`.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The method you're looking for is `fill()`:

```
$user = User::where ("username","rok"); // note that this shortcut is available if the comparison is =
$new_user_data = array(...);
$user->fill($new_user_data);
$user->save();
```

Actually, you could do `$user->fill($new_user_data)->save();` but I find the separate statements a little easier to read and debug.

Comment: It's a shame they don't have update() or save() with the new data...but this works. Also be sure to look into the Ardent package (it makes things much nicer with validation and updating uniques).

Comment: Did anyone get this error :-
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fill()

Comment: I'm also getting error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fill()  please someone help!

Comment: Regarding the `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::fill()`, there is a difference between using the query builder and Eloquent methods. See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries vs https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent.

Answer (score 10):

You are looking for this:

```
$user = User::where("username","rok")
                ->update( 
                       array( 
                             "email" => "rok@rok.com",
                             "is_superuser" => 1,
                             // ..
                             )
                       );
```

Refer : http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#insert-update-delete

Answer (score 5):

I should suggest to use shorter code, such as

```
    $new_user_data=array('a'=>'n','b'=>'m');
    $user=User::whereUsername('rok');//camelCase replaces "=" sign
    $user->fill($new_user_data)->save();
```

Or even shorter

```
    $new_user_data=array('a'=>'n','b'=>'m');
    User::whereUsername('rok')->update($new_user_data);//camelCase replaces "=" sign
```

I believe the last statement is easier to debug and looks nicer.

Warning: If your table contains many users named 'rok' both mentioned statements will update all those registers at once.  You should always update registers with the id field value.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
// took required data out of the request
$postData = request(
    [
        'firstName',
        'lastName',
        'address1',
        'address2',
        'address3',
        'postcode',
        'phone',
        'imageURL',
    ]
);
// persisted it to the database
DB::table('users')
    ->where('id', auth()->user()->id)
);
```

Comment: I think you missed a few lines there