# Why does lumen have issues identifying the columns?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, lumen

I'm new to Lumen and I'm trying to update multiple rows in a single query with eloquent Model. 
I get this error currently:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `articles` set `0` = {"title":"my blogMASSUPDATE","description":"myblogdescriptionMASSUPDATE","status":3}, `1` = {"title":"my blogMASSUPDATE","description":"myblogdescriptionMASSUPDATE","status":3}, `2` = {"title":"my blog33MASSUPDATE","description":"myblogdescription33MASSUPDATE","status":3}, `articles`.`updated_at` = 2019-12-02 08:23:28 where `status` = ==)
```

The JSON payload looks like this:

```
{
    "array1": [{
        "title": "my blogMASSUPDATE",
        "description": "myblogdescriptionMASSUPDATE",
        "status": 3
    }, {
        "title": "my blogMASSUPDATE",
        "description": "myblogdescriptionMASSUPDATE",
        "status": 3
    }, {
        "title": "my blog33MASSUPDATE",
        "description": "myblogdescription33MASSUPDATE",
        "status": 3
    }]
}
```

The code inside my controller looks like this:

```
public function massUpdate($id, Request $request){
  $this->validate($request, [
    'array1' => 'present|array',
    'array1.*.title' => 'required',
    'array1.*.description' => 'required'
  ]);

  $data = $request->getContent();
  $data = json_decode($data, true);

  Article::where('status', $id)->update($data['array1']);


}
```

This is the routercode:

```
  $router->put('articles/massUpdate/{id}', 'ArticleController@massUpdate');
```

And this is the URL used for the http request in my RESTClient (see restclient.net):

```
http://localhost:8080/api/articles/massUpdate/3
```

I don't understand what the problem is, the referenced columns exist and there are also fields matching the specified values.

EDIT:
I tried this solution:
[Laravel 4: how to update multiple fields in an Eloquent model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14878095/laravel-4-how-to-update-multiple-fields-in-an-eloquent-model)

The suggested code:

```
$user = User::where ("username","rok"); // note that this shortcut is available if the comparison is =
$new_user_data = array(...);
$user->fill($new_user_data);
$user->save();
```

Now when I refactor my code to use the above shown syntax inside my context:

```
  $rows = Article::where('status', $id);

  $rows->fill($data);
```

I get the error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::fill()
```

Which has also been pointed out already in the comments of the above referenced SO answer. 
Can anyone enlight me how to deal with this problem, because this code looks like it would do exactly what I want: dynamically mass updating the referenced fields.

Answer (score 1):

firstly look at this [Laravel-update](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#updates)

Next if you want mass update try this

```
->update('column_name'=>$data['array1']);
```

EDIT:
Builder don't have method like fill, if you wrote this ->

```
 $data=
        [
            'title' => 'my blogMASSUPDATE',
            'description' => 'myblogdescriptionMASSUPDATE',
            'status' => 3,
        ];

    $id=1;
    $rows = new Test();
    $rows->fill($data)->save();
```

You should see something like this in the database -> 
[image]

Fill not update record but create a new one

UPDATE:Ok i found something similar try this ->

```
         $data=[
        [
            'title' => 'my blogMASSUPDATE',
            'description' => 'myblogdescriptionMASSUPDATE',
            'status' => 3,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'my blog3MASSUPDATE',
            'description' => 'myblogdescriptionMASSUPDATE',
            'status' => 3,
        ],
        [
            'title' => 'my blog33MASSUPDATE',
            'description' => 'myblogdescription33MASSUPDATE',
            'status' => 3,
        ]
        ];
        $id=3;
    collect($data)->each(function ($item) use($id){
        Test::where('status', $id)->update($item);
    });
```

Comment: @baryon123 check Update

Answer (score 0):

Check please, I think must work:

```
$data = '{
    "array1": [{
        "title": "my blogMASSUPDATE",
        "description": "myblogdescriptionMASSUPDATE",
        "status": 3
    }, {
        "title": "my blogMASSUPDATE",
        "description": "myblogdescriptionMASSUPDATE",
        "status": 3
    }, {
        "title": "my blog33MASSUPDATE",
        "description": "myblogdescription33MASSUPDATE",
        "status": 3
    }]
}';


$data = json_decode($data, true);

foreach ( $data['array1'] as $item ) {
    Article::where('status', $id)->update($item);
}
```